# Possible to get Zurb Foundation 4 select drop-downs to work on mobile browsers?

Tags: css, html-select, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks

I can't scroll options in a Foundation 4 select drop-down on **any** mobile browser. Which makes Foundation's select drop-down pretty useless. Is there a way to get it to work?

Comment: Could you post an example of it not working? In my brief test (http://metadept.com/test/) it seems to 'work' by scaling the page body to accommodate the menu size, which isn't very satisfying but doesn't prevent it from being used. (Tested in mobile Chrome and Firefox on my Nexus 7)

Comment: Do you mean if you put a `select` element inside a form having a `custom` class it won't work? [See this link](http://goo.gl/vEkP0), I made a test for you. That works on my android's browser webkit 534.30 (version 4 mobile safari).

Comment: @von - your test doesn't work on my iPhone. I can't scroll it. This is exactly the issue. I know this has problems on other android browsers, I guess you have one that works.

Comment: @metadept look at von's example. I think you're example only works because clicking an option doesn't close the dropdown

Comment: @at. Unfortunately I don't have an iPhone available at the moment to test with; I'll take another look at it on Monday.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Foundation 4. The issue is listed as "Open" in Github. https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2090. No idea when it will be fixed though

Comment: @user1 - yes, that bug was opened by me...

Comment: @at. - Here is a quick and dirty fix to get it working until the Zurb team fixes it. Use some server side or client side code to check if the user agent contains "iPhone" or "iPad" and apply the following CSS rule .dropdown ul{
  max-height:2000px !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. The only way (afaik) to solve this was not making use of custom-forms and build your own dropdown *like amazon* does:

```
<span id="nav-search-in" class="nav-sprite nav-facade-active" style="width: auto;">
   <span id="nav-search-in-content" style="width: auto; overflow: visible;">All</span>
   <span class="nav-down-arrow nav-sprite"></span>
   <select id="searchDropdownBox" class="searchSelect" style="top: 0px;">
        <option value="search-alias=aps" selected="selected">All Departments</option>
        <option value="search-alias=watches">Watches</option>
    </select>
 </span>
```

Set select's opacity to 0 (see other styles on their webpage) and trigger dropdown by clicking the down-arrow span.